# imposing conditions on an array within a function

Tags: functions, list-manipulation

Let's say I have the following function

```
ClearAll[f];
SetAttributes[f, HoldFirst];
f[S_, x_, y_, z_, Lx_, Ly_, Lz_] := (
    S[[x, y, z]] = 1; 
    S[[x+1, y, z]] = 2; 
    S[[x, y+1, z]] = 3; 
    S[[x, y, z+1]] = 4;
)
```

Sometimes I need to have a modified function which has an extra condition that when $z=L_z$ and you have $L_z+1$ inside the argument, then $x\rightarrow x+1$

```
ClearAll[f];
SetAttributes[f, HoldFirst];
f[S_, x_, y_, z_, Lx_, Ly_, Lz_] := (
    If[z == Lz, 
        {
            S[[x, y, z]] = 1; 
            S[[x+1, y, z]] = 2; 
            S[[x, y+1, z]] = 3; 
            S[[x+1, y, z+1]] = 4;
        }
        , (* else *)
        {
            S[[x, y, z]] = 1;
            S[[x+1, y, z]] = 2;
            S[[x, y+1, z]] = 3;
            S[[x, y, z+1]] = 4;
        }
    ];
)
```

Since my actual function is much bigger than this example and I need to make such small changes many times, I was wondering if I can impose such a change directly in the original function in some manner?

Comment: Does adding this definition do what you expect? `f[S_, x_, y_, Lz_, Lx_, Ly_, Lz_] := f[S, x+1, y, Lz, Lx, Ly, Lz]`

Comment: No, $x\rightarrow x+1$ only when $L_z+1$ is in the argument and not for just $z=L_z$

Comment: $L_z +1$ in what argument exactly? I see no $L_z +1$ anywhere in your example.

Comment: If you see the If statement in the second snippet, then for $z=L_z$, I take $x\rightarrow x+1$ (in comparison to the first snippet) when there is $z+1$ in the argument

Comment: And how is that related to `Lz` ?

Comment: Because the change is made for $z=L_z$. I am not sure what is unclear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhap the following modification will work for you

```
f[S_, x_, y_, z_, Lx_, Ly_, Lz_] := With[{w=Boole[z == Lz]},
    S[[x,y,z]]=1; S[[x+1,y,z]]=2; S[[x,y+1,z]]=3; S[[x+w,y,z+1]]=4];
```